# Notification small icon color not changing Pushwoosh Android SDK

Tags: android, notifications, pushwoosh

I am using Pushwoosh Android SDK for `push notification`,

I am facing issue with the small icon color when expanding the notification bar, it should be in dark color, check screenshot with the affected devices with **Android 7.0**, and it's working fine on other devices

[image: Samsung S6 with Android 7.0 OS]

please advise,

Answer (score 0):

For those who will come here with the same problem.
I met this issue when used one big icon for all screen sizes, the problem disappeared when i added to project smaller icons for different screen sizes. May be the problem is the system not able to handle too big icon.